# PI Calculator, Interview Challenge

Tags: c#, interview-questions, numerical-methods

Greg Beech says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406948/5398076) that he asks C# candidates to produce a formula that calculates PI Given that Pi can be estimated using the function \$4 * (1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \dots)\$.

I'm far from C# interview ready, but I like the challenge. Here is my attempt at the formula. Let me know if there is a better way to do it.

```
using System;

class MainApp 
{
    static void Main () 
    {
        double number = 0;
        double pi;
        int i = 1;

        do 
        {
            if ((i/2) % 2 == 0)
            {
                number += (double)(1) / i;
            }
            else
            {
                number -= (double)(1) / i;
            }
            pi = 4 * number;
            i += 2;
        } while (Math.Round(pi,5) != 3.14159);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Pi can be found using the formula 4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...) with {0} iterations.\n" +
        "At this point 4 is multiplied by: {1} to get {2}\n" +
        "This Rounds up to: {3}",i,number,pi,Math.Round(pi,5));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like pi = 4 * number; every loop is a step the could be avoided

Comment: @paparazzi Pi at 3.14159 is what the loop is searching for. Do you mean that the loop should look for the intended modifier (.785396...) instead?

Comment: No I mean operate on pi directly.

Comment: @Paparazzi thank you for your comment. I don't know what you mean right now, but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: I posted a solution.  Accept in minutes does give you much to consider.

Comment: Hard coding a pi constant into a pi approximator looks like cheating to me. I would hang onto an underestimate and an overestimate and stop looping once the first 6 digits of them are the same.

Comment: @mm201 That would be a bad plan is it does not converge in that manner.  At 6 I think it works but at more digits the problem is that it is high and slowly comes down.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's more a weakness of the algorithm's slow convergence and you would still have the same problem even if you hard coded 3.1415926535 into the program. And 6 digits will be effectively instant either way.

Comment: @mm201 I think there is more to it but comments are not for debate.

Comment: There are two parts to the question. **1)** *Can you write a loop which adds the next series term in each iteration?* You've proved you can do that part; your code is fine. **2)** *For any desired precision, do you know when you can stop iterating?* This is a comparatively harder question (and perhaps more interesting). I agree that you've "cheated" =P Since this is just for fun, I challenge you to come up with a better solution for the second question.

Comment: Depending on type of job you might want to use [Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: [This paper](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P45.pdf) shows that if you truncate at an appropriate number of terms you get the predicted error --- but the error is not only predicted, but predictable, so you can, by fixing the predicable error, get many more digits.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In an interview it usually doesn't matter if you actually solve the problem. What is most important is the way you (try to) solve it. If they don't tell you it should be the possibly fastest solution ever you should not optimize it prematurely but instead show that you know how to write SOLID code like encapsulate propertly, make the code testable etc. show that you know the techniques.

---

Here you could split the logic up into multiple methods for example you could have one generating the alternating sequence `[1, -3, 5, -7, 9, -11, ...]` that you can validate with a test:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AlternatingSequence()
{
    var i = 1;
    yield return i;
    var b = false;
    while (true) yield return ((b = !b) ? -1 : 1) * (i = i + 2);
}
```

then you can work on the PI itself and use it for the actual calculation which is then as simple as a LINQ expression:

```
public static double EstimatePI(int sumLength) 
{
    return (4 * AlternatingSequence().Take(sumLength).Sum(x => 1.0 / x));
}

var pi = EstimatePI(500_000).Dump(); // 3,14159065358969
```

---

There's all kind of stuff you can show you are familiar with in this simple task like DI or strategy pattern:

```
public static double EstimatePI(int sumLength, IEnumerable<int> sequenceGenerator) 
{
    return (4 * sequenceGenerator.Take(sumLength).Sum(x => 1.0 / x));
}

var pi = EstimatePI(500_000, AlternatingSequence);
```

or even more advanced DI and encapsulation

```
class PiCalculator
{ 
    private readonly IEnumerable<int> _sequenceGenerator;

    public PiCalculator(IEnumerable<int> sequenceGenerator)
    {
        _sequenceGenerator = sequenceGenerator;
    }

    public double EstimatePi(int sumLength)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or you can add an interface to show you know what abstraction means:

```
interface IPiCalculator
{ 
    double EstimatePi(int sumLength);
}
```

---

Is this an overkill? It might be but it shows me that you are able to write modular and testable code. Writing short code is a good thing too but if you write only five lines inside a `Main` in a job interview, you'll go home without any prospects of getting the job. Again, in an inteview you should sell your coding skills and not show how smart you are in solving something with a fewest possible lines of code that no one can verify.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This seems like good advice, and it gives me some topics to learn more about.

Comment: Does this ever get to 3.1415926536?  That is a correct number.

Comment: What does the underscore do here: `var pi = EstimatePI(500_000).Dump();` ?

Comment: @beppe9000 nothing; its a digit separator for readability.

Comment: @Paparazzi it gets pretty close to that number with `500_000_000` and `AsParallel().Sum(x => 1.0 / x)` but that's not the point and I didn't try to solve it any faster or optimal way but rather to make a point that for an interview the way how you get to the desired result counts more then the actual solution. Implementing it inside the `Main` is not a challange and won't win you a job.

Comment: Pretty close.  Even with 1,000,000,000  is only get to 3.14159265 and take 530 times as long as my solution.    The interview may actually care about the answer.  Customers do.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with @t3chb0t use of "digit seperator" there is this link https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/216

Comment: If someone produced something as overcomplicated as this, I'd consider that a very bad sign. Mind you, I'd suggest a good strategy for an interviewee is to ask the interviewers to be more precise about what kind of solution they're looking for.

Comment: @JackAidley bad sign? because you can test it? because you can exchange the pi-calculator later or easily mock it?  I wouldn't say it's too much. There is one more thing about such things... if I'm looking for a junior developer it might be ok if he just can write a loop or compile a working program inside the Main but in case of a senior dev I expect nothing less then this. Perhaps we should first define the required level and the position of the candidate ;-)

Comment: I find it hard to imagine how you can write a Pi finding function you can't test. This is no more or less testable than any of the other solutions wrapped in a function. I suspect how people will react to this code depends on their background; me, I wrote computer games. To me this is needlessly slow, complex, code.

Comment: @JackAidley but it's not about the pi function, it's an interview question. how else you'd like to show that you can write modular, solid and testable code? it's just a simple example that is solvable during such a job interview. If I let you write a windows service importing xls files from an ftp server into a database with extensive logging and reporting you'll need a month or two for this.

Comment: Yeah, it's an interview question, but in interview I still expect people to produce appropriate code. You want to show off your ability to write modular code, I'd want you to showcase your ability to deal with the problem in an appropriate way.

Comment: @JackAidley I think the background thing is a good point. If I were writing a menu system for a game I'd focus on making it lightweight, if I were writing a menu system for a desktop program (e.g. a word processor) intended to be continually updated and supported I'd accept something heavier if the extra code provides other benefits.

Answer (score 26):

I'm going to give an alternative approach to [tchbot's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158551/23902)

There are places where SOLID prinicpals are required.

I don't see this as one of them. Here, we have a simple "Are you capable of writing a loop" question - about the same level as [the Fizz Buzz test](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest).

Really, the function is described in one line, and when applying mathematical formulas, I think it's OK to write terse code.

```
using namespace System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double t = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1, m = 1, c=0; c < 1000000; i+=2,m*=-1,++c) {
            t += (1.0/i)*m; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("pi={0}", 4*t);
    }
}
```

---

Note one principal I'm applying here: The length of a variable name should be proportional to its scope. ( [Bob C. Martin](https://twitter.com/unclebobmartin/status/39333982050975744?lang=en). )

I could name the variable `m` something descriptive like `togglingNegativeMultiplier`, but as it's entire lifetime is over two lines of code a reader would be able to see what it is doing.

---

Incidentally, I wrote a performance test to compare the performance of the Linq solution against the performance of a simple loop. https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3e649

When calculating a million iterations:

- Time using Linq: 89 milliseconds
- Time using Loop: 10 milliseconds

Granted, there are situations where a nine-fold difference in performance matters, and some where it doesn't. But here we're writing number-crunching code, and in these areas performance tends to be important.

Comment: I wouldn't hire you if you wrote this code in an interview :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I may have dodged a bullet there :-] Seriously though, I would want a developer to indicate he can get the job done with the right level of design as befits the problem, and if they completely over-engineered it to the detriment of performance (and with respect I think yours is over-engineered) then I would have concerns.

Comment: I think you don't have to worry about over-enigneering, on the contrary, under-engineering is a much bigger problem because the god-class/method ant-pattern is much more popular.

Comment: In an interview setting, the problem is just a toy problem to read your thought process. Your thought process was  to try and find an efficient algorithm. t3chb0t's thought process was more architecturally oriented. I don't think any solution is over-designed or under-designed, and both interviewees would certainly be asked subsequent questions to clarify their solution ("Do you think your solution is performant enough?", "What if I wanted to swap the implementation of the algorithm at runtime?", etc.).

Comment: Though personally, I don't think it's ever acceptable to use 1-character variable names unless they have obvious semantics attached to them, e.g. `i` for a loop variable or `a` in `a**2 + b**2 == c**2`. In your solution, I think `t` is a particularly bad name, magnified by the fact that the algorithm is not encapsulated in a function with a clear name.

Comment: @VincentSavard Additionally I think naming "m" as "sign" would adequately describe what it's doing without wasting a bunch of space.  I also wouldn't stuff it into the for loop line; nothing wrong with the loop body having a `sign *= -1;` line.

Comment: This " The length of a variable name should be proportional to it's scope." is, in my opinion, insufficient. Scope does not have any direct relationship to complexity. I would always require any and all code first and foremost always be maintainable. If the interviewee writes for obfuscation (implicitly or explicitly) vs clarity then that has always been a major negative. IF followup questions persuade me that they can write maintainable as in easily understood code, then I would allow then on probation. Exception: Position is very vertical/niche oriented with no horizontal interaction.

Comment: Forget SOLID, ask whether code needs to be testable. I'd say something like this obviously does.

Comment: @BenAaronson if code is SOLID then it's Testable.

Comment: I want to upvote this for the general principle, and downvote it for the variable names.

Comment: @P.Roe but not vice versa

Comment: its scope, not "it's" scope

Comment: Seeing `m *= -1` does not immediately make me think 'the sign is being inverted', `m = -m` would be much more readable.

Comment: If you write code using exclusively one character names in an interview setting, good luck convincing me that you won't similarly name your real variables with unused random letters. This is even more important when you do something clever like jam all your logic for the entire loop on two lines with variable names that don't even communicate what they are doing. An interview isn't the time to see how clever you can be and optimize the number of bytes your code contains, it's to show interviewers you can write cohesive and meaningful code and know what you are doing.

Comment: @BenAaronson agreed!

Answer (score 20):

Flavio's answer addresses a part of something that matters greatly for this kind of problem: rounding errors will kill you. If you look at the expression:

$$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+...$$

This is the same as

$$\frac{3-1}{1\times3} + \frac{7-5}{5\times 7} + ...$$

It is easy to see that the nth term in this sequence is

$$\frac{2}{(4\times n-3)(4\times n-1)}$$

Now if you need a certain number of digits of precision, you first compute the number of terms you need - now that we have the terms in pairs, they are all contributing a positive amount. This converges extremely slowly... you can estimate this approximately by noticing that

$$\sum_n^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\approx\int_{n-\frac12}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n-\frac12}$$

So if you need the answer to be right to better than 5 digits, you need to sum at least 100,000 elements - and as the required accuracy goes up, you need to carry a LOT more significant figures. Alternatively, the smart person adds the estimated error term at the end - and gets awfully close to the right answer with not a lot of calculation. See below.

Now you may know that a single precision floating point number contains about 23 bits of precision - about 7 digits. This will really mess up your attempt to get even 4 digits of precision if you don't work backwards, starting with the smallest numbers (which means you can carry digits beyond the 7th decimal, until the sum gets bigger).

So the steps you take:

1. Formulate the expression to be monotonic
2. Determine the rate of convergence
3. Find an expression for the number of terms you need to reach a certain precision
4. Execute the calculations in an order that maximizes the accuracy

Only if all the above fail should you resort to brute force (using double precision and above, keeping going until you are sure your answer is no longer changing).

Of course, as others pointed out, for a "pure software" job, a lot of issues of properly structured code come into play - but if the task is one of numerical analysis, not just dropping a few lines of code, then the above considerations really matter.

For example, evaluating the expression for the first 100000 terms in the "forward" direction, using single precision (which emphasizes the problem), you get

```
pi=3.14138389
```

Doing it in the "backward" direction (starting with the smallest term) you get

```
pi=3.14158773
```

The difference: -0.00020385; they are different from the 5th significant figure onwards even though floating point precision "should be better than that" - but rounding errors compound! You can see that the "backward" method is getting close to 3.14159, while the "forward" method will never get there.

Here is some C code I wrote to demonstrate these points - note that the actual loop that does the piece you asked about takes just four lines. I realize you are looking for comments on your C# code, but the principles I outlined transcend the language you use.

```
// code that computes the value of pi by evaluating the first few terms
// of the infinite series
// pi = 4*(1/1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...)
//
// three important points:
// rounding error is reduced by evaluating starting with the small values
// rounding error is further reduced by pairing the values
// finally, an analytical estimate of the residual error is used to make the
// result significantly more accurate

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int N=100;             // number of values to include
    double PI=2*acos(0.0); // to confirm the accuracy later
    float forwardSum, backwardSum, residualSum;
    forwardSum=0;

    for(int ii=1; ii<=N; ii++) {
        forwardSum+=8./((4*ii-3.)*(4*ii-1.));
    }

    // ***** this is the code that does the heavy lifting *****
    backwardSum=0;
    for(int ii=N; ii>=1; ii--) {
        backwardSum+=8./((4*ii-3.)*(4*ii-1.));
    }
    // backwardSum now contains our estimate of pi

    // analytically we know the error should be
    residualSum = 0.5/N;

    printf("Starting with big terms, after %d pairs pi=%.8f\n", N, forwardSum);
    printf("Starting with small terms, after %d pairs pi=%.8f\n", N, backwardSum);
    printf("difference between directions: %.8f\n", backwardSum - forwardSum);
    printf("estimated residual sum = %e\n", residualSum);
    printf("updated estimate of pi: %.8f\n", backwardSum + residualSum);
    printf("after correction, error in pi is %e\n", PI-(backwardSum +residualSum));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Starting with big terms, after 100 pairs pi=3.13659286
Starting with small terms, after 100 pairs pi=3.13659263
difference between directions: -0.00000024
estimated residual sum = 5.000000e-03
updated estimate of pi: 3.14159274
after correction, error in pi is -8.742278e-08
```

Using single precision, the error is reduced to about 1 part in \$ 10^7 \$, just as we expect as the limit of accuracy. Incidentally, the error correction term is so good that you get the "right" answer with just 100 pairs of terms.

While brute force is sometimes all you need, a little analysis is not a bad trick to keep up your sleeve.

Comment: Very  good numerical analysis and using reversion summation.  Minor clarity addition: the "nth" term of the summation used here is the "nth" _pair_ of OP's original series.

Comment: BTW, rather than `8./((4*ii-3.)*(4*ii-1.));`, perhaps `8.0f/((4*ii-3)*(4*ii-1));` - avoid `double` math.

Comment: Very good! Also, as a way of accelerating convergence, plot the partial results pi(n) as a function of 1/n and extrapolate the function to 0.

Answer (score 11):

There is clearly no 'best way' to do this.
From a 'Numerical Analysis' approach,
you should never sum that way a series with alternating-sign terms:
loss of accuracy and slow convergence speed can be expected.
Use simple arithmetic to sum the terms in pairs,
and then iterate by two units at a time.
If you do this, you will gain
a lot both in accuracy and in convergence speed.
So the expression I would add is :

1 / (n*n + n)

Comment: Math always beats anything else ;-]

Comment: Is that expression correct? I would use `8/((4n+1)*(4n+3))` with n running over whole numbers.  No need to just use odds or every other odd, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your expression is wrong. It would give `1/0` or `1/2` for the first term (depending on whether you start from `n=0` (like a real programmer) or not. Whereas the sum of the first two terms is `2/3`.

Comment: I agree, I think your maths might be wrong:
`1/x - 1/(x+2)`
`=2/(x*(x+2))`

Comment: @JackAidley Clearly the `if(n >0)`is implicit.

Comment: +1, but the expression is wrong. There could be some ambiguity depending on whether you let n=1, 2, 3, ... or n=1, 3, 5, ..., but either way, I don't think this is right. The correct expression would need to generate either 2/3 or -2/15 (depending on how the terms are grouped), but this expression never achieves these values for any integer n.

Answer (score 8):

## Observations and Suggestions

- Operate on pi directly.
- You can eliminate the `pi = 4 * number;`.
- You are using more operations than are necessary.
- I prefer `decimal` over `double` here for precision.
  `Decimal` is slower and at 6 digits of precision  I don't think `double` would get you in trouble.  More precision `double` could introduce errors which are not self correcting.
- Do 2 iterations in one overall iteration of the loop and eliminate
  the modulo operator `%`
- Eliminate the casting of `int` to `decimal`
- The average of + and - is going to be the best current estimate
- The answer will between + and - if no rounding error as been
  introduced

  ```
  public static decimal PI3()
  {   
      decimal pi = 4m, iteration = 3m;
      do
      {  
           pi -= 4m / iteration;
           iteration += 2m;
           pi += 4m / iteration;
           iteration += 2m;
           //Debug.WriteLine(pi);
      } while (Decimal.Round(pi, 5)  !=  3.14159m);
      return Decimal.Round(pi, 5);
  }
  ```

In reply to OP's question in comments:

Test this versus your solution or other proposed solutions:

```
public static decimal PI4()
{
    decimal pi = 4m, iteration = 3m, piAvg;
    do
    {   
        pi = Decimal.Subtract(pi, Decimal.Divide(4m, iteration));
        piAvg = pi;
        iteration = decimal.Add(iteration, 2m);
        pi = Decimal.Add(pi, Decimal.Divide(4m, iteration));
        piAvg = Decimal.Divide(Decimal.Add(pi, piAvg), 2m);
        iteration = decimal.Add(iteration, 2m);
        if(decimal.Add(iteration, 1m) % 100000m == 0) {
            Debug.WriteLine(piAvg);
        }
    } while (Decimal.Round(piAvg, 10) != 3.1415926536m);      //3.1415926535897932384626433833
    return Decimal.Round(piAvg, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean now about operating on pi directly. I'm curious if 2 iterations in the loop is actually optimal. Can you explain why this is preferred?

Comment: As stated:   Do 2 iteration in the loop and eliminate the modus %.  Every operation takes time.

Comment: I'm not convinced, I actually tested our two versions and my original code packaged into a function appears to be significantly faster than PI3(). http://ideone.com/t73laU

Comment: @LearningToCSharp  Not convinced of what?  You don't agree that every operation takes time?  As I stated decimal has more precision.  But it is like 15x slower.   Try this with double.

Comment: I agree that every operation takes time, and that precision is important. I'm not convinced that iterating twice between each evaluation is ideal. I created a new test where my original code is modified to use decimal and both functions return the iterations. The original is still twice as fast, and PI3() seems to require more iteration. http://ideone.com/NuJq6W

Comment: @LearningToCSharp OK I will look into it

Comment: With this particular formula, the precision of the result is +/- (1/(2i+1)), and with doubles, a program will run out of a reasonable amount of time long before rounding related to double precision math impacts the result by more than +/- (1/(2i+1)). A half billion loops only results in 9 digits of accuracy, and doubles hold about 18 digits, so even after half billion loops, the maximum error from double precision rounding will not affect the 9 most significant digits.

Comment: Why not use the well-known error approximation for alternating series?

Comment: @rcgldr OPs solution does not converge on 10.  What if you don't want to stop at half billion?  What if you want more than 9 significant digits as in the code I posted?

Comment: @Paparazzi - The issue for 10 digits isn't due to using double, the issue is that i needs to be a `long` not an `int`, since 10^9 is greater than the maximum value that can be stored in a 32 bit signed integer.

Comment: @rcgldr I hold with decimal for precision.  Thank you.

Comment: In theory, doing modulo division every loop iteration should be very expensive and therefore much slower than a design which avoids that operation. However, the compiler may be automagically optimizing your modulo-even-or-odd test into a much cheaper bit-operation, which might explain why you're not seeing an expected performance difference.

Comment: @brian_o I am seeing the performance difference of my solution is much faster than OP.

Comment: Any reason why you call static methods on `Decimal` explicitly instead of writing normal algebra with normal operators?

Comment: @RomanStarkov Because it is there?

Comment: @Paparazzi It's there so that the compiler has something to call when you write `pi = pi - 4m / iteration`. Isn't that a lot more readable than `pi = Decimal.Subtract(pi, Decimal.Divide(4m, iteration));`?

Comment: @RomanStarkov Actually I would write pi +=

Comment: @Paparazzi PI4 is way faster, nice work. http://ideone.com/rTWszF

Answer (score 3):

I think what you came up is a good start. I've edited your code to improve and make more concise. It's not the best code, but I hope it helps you.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    double number = 0;
    double pi;
    int i = 1;
    bool sign = true; // we use a boolean to sum or subtract

    do 
    {
        double div = (double)(1.0 / i);  // calculate the ratio
        number += (sign ? div : -div); // sum or subtract depending on sign being true or false

        pi = 4 * number;
        i += 2;
        sign = !sign;  // toggle sign

    } while ((Math.Round(pi,5) != 3.14159));

    Console.WriteLine("Pi can be found using the formula 4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...) with {0} iterations.\n" +
    "At this point 4 is multiplied by: {1} to get {2}\n" +
    "This Rounds up to: {3}",(i-1)/2,number,pi,Math.Round(pi,5)); // to know the iteration we use i-1 / 2

}
```

Comment: You have some good changes. Using the ? is a good idea, and the iterations should be divided by 2. I actually started with a toggle as well, but decided to use (i/2) % 2 instead. It still works using ? like this: "number += ((i/2) % 2 == 0 ? div : (-1.0*div));"

Comment: Your variable names disgust me. "div"? "number"? "i"? "pi"? How about "currentTerm" "piApproximation" etc.

Comment: @theonlygusti apart from div, the other variables are from the original question.

Comment: @peval27 yeah, and this is a code review site where you should show others how to code better. That includes fixing variable names.

Comment: @theonlygusti And this is a site where you should show that you can critique code professionally and politely. Saying that the names "disgust" you is not constructive criticism.

Comment: You should change `(-1.0*div)` to `-div`, but otherwise this is much more readable than some of the other examples.

Answer (score 3):

#### What I think is wrong with the code - it's hard to understand

Here's what I think all good code should do:

1. First and foremost it must be understandable. Most of the code you write will be read many more times than edited. There are no comments - which is not necessarily bad if the code is self-explanatory. that's what we should aim for.
2. It must be easy to maintain
3. and if required must be easy to make changes
4. It must actually work: where are your tests!?!

#### Is it worth writing OOP code or should we go quick and dirty?

Writing pure OOP code might take a little bit longer (but it will probably be more robust). Is it worth it? It might not be. but since this is a hypothetical, let's go down the OOP way:

Your code does not make use of "objects" which send "messages" to each other. (Please google that if you don't know what it means). You've got conditionals in your code which also supply behaviour. OOP is meant to get you to have objects supply the behaviour and to separate conditionals from behaviour as much as possible.

#### Here is the Summary Code:

```
public class Pie
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Estimates pi based on the number of fractions we desire it to estimate by.
    /// The way I view it: you basically have 4 * (element0 + element1 + element2 etc.)
    /// where element0, element1 etc are instances of the Element class.        
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elementCount"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double Estimate(int elementCount)
    {
        ElementCollection ec = new ElementCollection(elementCount);
        return 4 * ec.AddAllElements();
    }
}
```

#### Here is the Full Code:

```
namespace BKTest
{
    public class Pie
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Estimates pi based on the number of fractions we desire it to estimate by.
        /// The way I view it: you basically have 4 * (element0 + element1 + element2 etc.)
        /// where element0, element1 etc are instances of the Element class.
        /// I use a factory method to instantiate the element types and use polymorphism to differentiate
        /// between the two different types of elements that are currently out there: Element0 and the others: Element1, Element2 etc .
        /// Element zero is different because you can't divide by zero! (This probably won't make any sense)
        /// Till you attempt the problem yourself.
        ///
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="elementCount"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double Estimate(int elementCount)
        {
            ElementCollection ec = new ElementCollection(elementCount);
            return 4 * ec.AddAllElements();
        }
    }

    public class ElementCollection
    {
        private int elementCount;

        public ElementCollection(int elementCount)
        {
            this.elementCount = elementCount;
        }

        public double AddAllElements()
        {
            double result = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < elementCount + 1; i++)
            {
                ElementN element = ElementFactory(i);
                result += element.Value();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public ElementN ElementFactory(int i)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                return new Element0(i);
            }
            else
            {
                bool even = (i % 2 == 0);

                if (even)
                {
                    return new ElementEven(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ElementOdd(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public class Element0 : ElementN
        {
            public Element0(int elementCount)
                : base(elementCount)
            {
            }

            public override int Sign()
            {
                return 1;
            }

            public override double PosivitveValue()
            {
                return 1.0;
            }
        }

        public class ElementEven : ElementN
        {
            public ElementEven(int elementCount)
                : base(elementCount)
            {
            }

            public override int Sign()
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public class ElementOdd : ElementN
        {
            public ElementOdd(int elementCount)
                : base(elementCount)
            {
            }

            public override int Sign()
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public abstract class ElementN
        {
            private int elementCount;

            public ElementN(int elementCount)
            {
                this.elementCount = elementCount;
            }

            virtual public double Value()
            {
                return Sign() * PosivitveValue();
            }

            virtual public double PosivitveValue()
            {
                return ((1.0) / (2.0 * elementCount + 1));
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Either the sign is positive or negative
            /// We could probably put this into its own class
            /// and have a factory method but we'll keep it like this for the moment
            /// till one day change requires us to change it. After all, a sign can only
            /// either be positive or negative. (apparently you can also multiple by the
            /// square root of (-1) but that's another matter.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            abstract public int Sign();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Here are the Tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace BKTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    internal class PieTest
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCase(0, 4)]
        [TestCase(1, 4 * (1 - 1.00 / 3.0))]
        [TestCase(2, 4 * (1 - 1.00 / 3.0 + 1 / 5.0))]
        [TestCase(3, 4 * (1 - 1.00 / 3.0 + 1 / 5.0 - 1 / 7.0))]
        [TestCase(4, 4 * (1 - 1.00 / 3.0 + 1 / 5.0 - 1 / 7.0 + 1 / 9.0))]
        public void Estimate_1Parameter_expect_fourMinusOneThird(int input, double output)
        {
            // set up
            double result = new Pie().Estimate(input);
            Assert.AreEqual(output, result);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note - originally the code was put on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/e84ec3448cb33515dc4851ad57f1363c))

#### Points about the code:

- API is simpler to read and understand. The main logic is hidden away.
- Easily amenable to change. What if the boss walks in and says he/she wants every 4th fraction to be: 1/e - will your code easily be able to handle that? I'd simply add a new ElementN sub-class called ElementE and add a conditional to my factory method and the changes would be made instantly.
- Compare my code with yours: I've put the conditionals in a factory - which is where they should be. everything is very neatly separated. I make use of an abstract class and then supply the various implementations of that abstract class. this is what good OOP code should do. And OOP is good because it is easily amenable to change, mainly because classes and methods are not tightly coupled together (please google it if you don't know what that means). As I see it, there are only three different types of fractions: the first one (which is one) then the second which is a positive fraction and the third, which is negative. and that's it! so I subclass everything into three class which supply the relevant behaviour. and I only need 1-2 conditionals to make the whole thing work. This is an OOP way of handling it. ask a functional programmer and he or she might do it a different way but then again, it's harder to change.

Comment: I think this would be an on-topic answer if the question had been asked on workplace.stackexchange.com, but this is codereview.stackexchange.com and the question is asking for a review of the code, not for tips on job interviews.

Comment: A non-docstring comment saying `// Provides an estimate of Pi` for a method named `EstimatePi` does not increase the reader's understanding of the code. I'd get rid of the comment and leave the well-named method. Or use proper C# docstring style, if the intent is to have it get picked up by tooling.

Comment: have updated thx for your comments

Comment: The bad thing about your solution is that it's on gist and not a part of the answer. _code does not make use of "objects" which send "messages" to each other_ I couldn't google for that. What do you mean by sending messages?

Comment: @t3chb0t try these links: https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5sYOSk8LTAhUHsJQKHUG4A3YQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9781846289620-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-452413-p173740637&usg=AFQjCNEDRylXcpXe0uqybdWk80xhQmQTsA&sig2=zNjn1H644SWkwZDIcHnwyQ  also here is a super short summary: https://bkspurgeon.github.io/BKSpurgeon.github.io/senders-receiver-messages/ here is another: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/what-is-message-passing-in-oo

Comment: @t3chb0t unfortunately Stackoverflow butchered the formatting so badly i had to put it in a gist. that way it is readable. i really had no other solution. the code is good in terms applying die hard OOP practices to the problem as an academic exercise. i hope you find it useful - it certainly is well worth studying to come to an understanding of it. any questions just ask and i'll try and clear it up for you!

Comment: What formatting problems did you have exactly? I cannot confirm that. I've never had any issues with the formatting.

Comment: @t3chb0t was pasting half in text and the other half in code. i struggled a little bit but then i said it's much easier in a gist. in any case, the important point is the code and what you can learn from it, rather than where it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code doesn't look straightforward and is a little confusing.
You use `int i` and then implicitly cast `i/2` to `int` to check if it is even.

The casting to double also seems weird, it would look better if it was `1.0 / i` or `1d / i`.

Also, you don't need to multiply by 4 every iteration, since multiplication distributes over addition.

My answer yould look like this, trying to make it very simple and readable.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses the formula 4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...) to estimate pi
/// </summary>
public static double EstimatePi(int iterations)
{
    double series = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        int sign = i.IsEven() ? 1 : -1;
        series += sign / (2d*i + 1);
    }
    return 4 * series;
}

private static bool IsEven(this int number)
{
    return (number % 2 == 0);
}
```

Comment: @StephenRauch thank you for your feedback! I have edited my answer, is it better now?